# Convert CGoban Java App for IOS

Tags: codenameone

I use a Java app on my Mac called CGoban.  http://www.gokgs.com/  It lets me play the game of Go against other humans logged into the server.  I would like to run it on my iPad.  Will Codename One do that?

The jar file is publicly available here:

http://files.gokgs.com/javaBin/cgoban.jar

A quick look through the jar reveals that it's written using Swing.  Is this likely to work out of the box?  Or, will there be some adaptation coding needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Codename One requires the source code for the compilation process.

You can't use Swing as is because that API wasn't designed for mobile. It should be easy enough to port for a developer but it's not something you can do from a binary jar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I can decompile the jar file back into source code.  If I do that, how much work is there to switch from Swing to something else?  What alternative to Swing would you recommend?

Comment: We have a builtin API that is similar to Swing. I would assume decompiling the jar is illegal and would likely result in code that's REALLY hard to compile

Comment: codename1 UI is more like AWT than swing, and it uses a significantly different event model.

Comment: No. The API is like Swing. You are talking about removing the J notation and fixing the hierarchy but that's just fluff. The lightweight approach and other core concepts (e.g. Content Pane, Painters etc) are pretty much Swing.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase it.  Codename1 doesn't have any swing compatible components, or for that matter any AWT compatible components.  The overall style of windowing is similar to both, but you have to build up from basic window classes where the least common denominator of Codename1 AWT and Swing lies.